# Isekai anime where the main character becomes a Forger and creates weapons by drawing them

Tags: story-identification, anime, magical-theory, isekai

I'm looking for a specific anime. In this anime, the main character is in another world with a girl (for some reason or another it's his wife). They go to some kind of learning institute where you can be a power fighter or a type of magician.

The girl is extremely strong but the MC does not posses the power or have the capacity to harness the energy in that world. There's another job that best suits the MC, a Forger. This is where the anime is distinctive from the rest in that a forger creates a weapon by **drawing** the weapon using a special pen infused with a magic crystal and since the MC has knowledge from his previous life and was a **damn good** artist he already qualifies to be a student in that field. He tries a number of things like a car, or machine gun and stuff (those didn't work out) but with his creations this is how he does battle.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Is this definitely an anime and not just a manga?

Answer (score 5):

in line with the comment @KMo made, there is [My Wife is a Demon Queen](https://www.readmng.com/my-wife-is-a-demon-queen), but that doesn't seem to have an anime.  It matches everything else exactly.

The main character is summoned to another world, gains a wife upon being summoned.  Since she is a demon, she has a lot of 'boundary force' which is used for magic.  The main character is called 'useless lumber' because he has little to no ability to use boundary force. They end up going to an academy, and he ends up in a class for forging, which is done by drawing using special pens and magical stones. He ends up making various modern/sci-fi objects using them. After some trial and error, he eventually works his way up to working cars/trucks/mechas, though initially he failed at those and made things like bicycles.

Comment: THANK YOU I THINK THATS IT!!!  i have this thing where i recall something i read or watched and even if i read it i remember it as if i watched it i give it life, its a bad habbit no wonder why i couldnt find it it something I READ lol

Comment: @DavonHorne you're welcome. The description was so spot on for the comic i figured it was probably this.  If this is what you are looking for, you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to it.