# Isekai manga where the protagonist is using science and logic in his spells at his magic high school

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I’ve been looking for this manga where the protagonist uses nuclear bomb logic in a magic battle, and other basic scientific theories behind his spell casting.

Comment: Do you have any other details about this manga? Was this a battle at the school where he used this nuclear spell, or was it a fight outside school? Does he have teamates/followers?  does he try to hide his identity?

Comment: This may not be true. At least I not found a manga of this but I have read the novel. Using science and logic at his spell could be Magus Tech ` https://www.novelupdates.com/series/magus-tech`

MC learn magic via science. Around 980 he can do nuclear bomb when he at 3rd stage wizard.All spell is based of science fundamental

Comment: I'm not sure if the manga ever shows this scene, but in the Light Novel Mahōka Kōkō no Rettōsei (The Irregular at Magic High school), one of the main characters can apparently induce nuclear fusion with his magic. There's a scene where he, using a magic sniper rifle to control it at a distance, basically blows up the Chinese Navy.

Comment: There are many stories with this as the premise. Can you remember any other details?

Comment: Flagging this as not having enough details, this is common enough a premise it’s basically its own subgenre at this point.

Comment: This one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75KZGVllCic ? Does anything look familiar?

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you are looking for *My Wife is a Demon Queen* also the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/231122/isekai-anime-where-the-main-character-becomes-a-forger-and-creates-weapons-by-dr/231199#231199).

In chapter 149, the manga talks about how a nuke works and why that makes the 'spell' the main character is using more powerful/deadly than a fireball.  The main character is going to a magic school, and is using the 'spell' in a tournament.

While I have been using spell, the main character is actually drawing things and having them appear.  This makes all of his abilities have some basis in scientific theories, and they are occasionally talked about for how he wins fights.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are thinking of [World Teacher - Isekaishiki Kyouiku Agent](https://myanimelist.net/manga/103436/World_Teacher__Isekaishiki_Kyouiku_Agent?q=world%20teacher&cat=manga). The MC uses science to be able to overwhelm even the headmaster of the academy, and has a few followers.

World Teacher follows a reincarnated secret agent instructor who dies on his last mission and is reborn as a magically inept infant. He eventually uses his magic to recreate the function of weapons from his past life. He tells his servants that he has memories of a past life, and carries the last name "Teach" or "Teacher" (fanlations aren't clear). The first bit of the story focuses on him gaining his two sibling followers and caring for his maid that has an incurable illness, before going off to magic school. He recreates the force of a grenade launcher in his entrance exam, but is forced to live in a run down old building because a noble disliked him for using colorless magic.

EDIT: he does use magic to simulate the effects of weapons, up to and including a nuke, through visualization, but doesn't lean as much into the hard science aspects of other series